# Advantages of using WCF to work with Sharepoint Services WSS3.0?

Tags: wcf, service, wss

what is your opinion or better off your practical experience using WCF to work with WSS instead of SP web services?

I am writing some custom library for our software to store and retrieve files from WSS document libraries using sharepoint web services.  I am not entirely happy with the performance of the sp web services - a bit too slow in many cases.

Now, microsoft claims a significant improvements in WCF over remoting and I am looking into a good way to use WCF for my file services.

Any suggestions or ideas?  Maybe a good source of coding practices or blogs?

Thanks a lot,
Val

Answer (score 0):

The SP web services are asmx services which use http.

If you create your own WCF services, you could use netTCP binding and get a performance boost.

However, then performance boost that you get is probably relativity small. You also get the extra work of creating the WCF services and the risk of errors in services that you write.

I would just use the standard SP web services, unless you have a very special situation / requirement.

Comment: Thanks Shiraz,

I don't think I have any special requirements beside a response time to less than a second for a single request.

The number of requests will be very minimal: 1-10 a minute.